# Compare values in a comma delimited string with values in a named range in Excel and stop at the first match

Tags: excel, csv, excel-formula, lookup

I have a spreadsheet with a column of comma delimited strings contain GUID values. I also have a column (named range) of individual GUID values.

I want to look up the values from each cell of CSV GUID values to see if any match values in a named range. I want to stop at the first match.

The cells with the comma delimited string can contain 0 or more comma separated values.

The named range is a column of unique values.

The result just needs to be yes/no for any value in the csv string that matches a value in the named range.

| Named range | CSV string to test | Is there a match? |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4b0927a8-c0ff-42dd-a0aa-e32192395db8 | c93d643b-09dd-4b29-b1fc-73610eaff1cf,1aef3a95-ea6b-49b1-ae2f-e05b060e08ae | No |
| d4766194-8a74-4c48-b16d-f5bc8d5f31d2 | b693b4fb-0d23-4109-a621-1b828b824454,b693b4fb-0d23-4109-a621-1b828b824454 | Yes |
| 40133ac3-33e0-4489-b321-a5d2387532f6 | b693b4fb-0d23-4109-a621-1b828b824454,b693b4fb-0d23-4109-a621-1b828b824454 | Yes |

---

Comment: FIND() will find strings, but without any sort of example it's difficult to show a possible solution. Excel help does show the use of find() though.

Comment: @SolarMike, good point on what it should look like, I updated the original.

Comment: So how about some more intelligent examples? finding "GUID" in the string "CSV string of GUIDs" is too easy and won't deal with any special situations. find("GUID","CSV string of GUIDs",1)

Comment: Essentially I have a set of short articles identified by GUIDs. There are links in the articles that go to either a short article in the set, or a longer one not in the set.  
Not sure if that explains it better

Comment: I don't understand why your second and third examples are returning `Yes`. What, exactly, is matching from the CSV string to test in the Named Range?

Comment: The named range has 2000 cells, this is only a couple of lines to illustrate. 

I have two types of articles, short and long. I want to find out if a short article links to another short article. The 2000 lines are the short articles, with the  CSV string containing the articles that short article links to. 

So, if an article links to 3 other articles, there will be 3 GUIDs in the CSV string. If one or more of the links are going to another short article, we have a match. If they go to a long article, no match. 

Not sure how else to describe it.

Comment: You posted a nice table, however the table is not usable for reproduction of your question, which should be the point of the table. It took me VBasics answer to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 4):

### Match Delimited Data

**`BYROW`**

```
=LET(sdata,A2:A21,ldata,C2:C11,dlm,",",yes,"Yes",no,"No",
    IF(BYROW(ldata,LAMBDA(r,
        COUNT(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(r,dlm),sdata))>0)),yes,no))
```

**`MMULT`**

```
=LET(sdata,A2:A21,ldata,C2:C11,dlm,",",yes,"Yes",no,"No",
    IF(MMULT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(dlm&TOROW(sdata)&dlm,
        dlm&ldata&dlm)),SEQUENCE(ROWS(sdata),,,0))>0,yes,no))
```

[image]

**Legacy Excel**

In cell `D2` and copy down.

```
=IF(COUNT(SEARCH(","&A$2:A$21&",",","&C2&","))>0,"Yes","No")
```

**(Possibly) Array Formula in Legacy Excel**

Not tested! Your feedback is welcome.

```
=IF(MMULT(TRANSPOSE(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(","&A$2:A$21&",",TRANSPOSE(
    ","&C$2:C$11&",")))),CEILING(1/ROW(A$2:A$21),1))>0,"Yes","No")
```

Comment: Wow, the answer explains the question better than the question and it's comments all together. *PS dropping the IF would return TRUE or FALSE already.*

Comment: I'm returning Yes/No!?

Comment: Yes, I mean *"Is there a match?"* "Yes/No" is similar to "TRUE/FALSE", but doesn't require an extra calculation step. Not wrong, just shorter/more efficient

Comment: Do you mean dropping the `>0`?

Comment: No, I mean dropping `=IF(..,"Yes","No")` and leave the rest. Like `=BYROW(C2:C11,LAMBDA(r,
        COUNT(XMATCH(TEXTSPLIT(r,","),AS:A21))>0))`

Comment: @P.b I only now figured out what you were talking about. Fixed it. Thanks.